# identify article usage by journal when viewing Google Analytics reports

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have an online publishing website with multiple journals & articles.
I use Google Analytics to track the page views for each article.
However, I want to compare data based on journal level, not article level.
For example, I want to be able to find top article page views on articles from journal(A), journal(B) & journal(C).

I checked Google's developer guide, It states that you can have groupings but only up to 5 groups, with each containing only 100 items.

I have 34 journals on my site, with each containing more than 100 articles.

How can I use Google Analytics to compare article page views between journals?

Comment: Have you tried passing in the information through [custom dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en), this allows for arbitrary categorization of hits on the Session, User or hit level.

Comment: In a content group you would not create an item for every article; rather you would create a single group that contains your 34 magazines and attribute each article to one of the group items. So content groups might still work for you.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Will definitely try it.

Comment: That sounds fair Eike. But if my journal count goes up to more than 100 items ? If I'm reading GAs documentation right each group can contain up to 100 items (journals in my case).

Comment: I am not sure where you get the 100 item limits from - the documentation says "Within each of those, there is no limit to the number of Content Groups you can define" (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853423?hl=en&ref_topic=1727167). However GA docs sometimes contradicts itself, so I'd be curios where you read this (then we can alert Google to this inconsistency and have the documentation fixed).

Comment: here (https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#contentGroup)

which means I only can have a 100 journal in each of the 5 groupings, that limits it to 500 journals only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this would be as follows:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'Journal A');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This assumes that you've [configured a custom dimension](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829) (hit-scoped) with index 1 in the GA interface.

Once you've done this, you can then use this Journal custom dimension by adding it as a secondary dimension in any standard report or by create a [custom report](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1151300?hl=en).

Comment: Thank you. This looks like a perfect solution to my use-case.